# Length of external lines in feynman diagrams (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-feynman

I would like to make the following diagram

[image: IDontUnderstandWhyThisFigureGetsBlackWhenItIsResized]

using `TikZ` (The above diagram was done using `feynmf` package). So far I have written this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \feynmandiagram [ horizontal=i to v1] {
    i -- [double] v1 -- [double] v2 -- [double] v3 -- [double] v1,
    v2 -- [double] o1,
    v3 -- [double] o2,
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and obtained this

[image: diagram2]

However, I can't figure out, how to decrease the length of the external lines. In addition, I can't figure out how to make lines crossed like in the first figure. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide a full MWE. `\documentclass` ... `\end{document}` See: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use the automatic placement algorithms in [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)), then unfortunately there's no straightforward way of shortening the external lines as the underlying algorithm has no idea of which lines are external.

It is possible to tweak how far the edges are drawn with `shorten <=(distance)` and `shorten >=(distance)` (the difference being whether it cuts off the start of the end); but this only affects the *drawing* of the edge and not the way the algorithm treats the edge length and as a result  I would not really recommend using this.  In particular, this will look weird if used in conjunction with the `particle` style as text will be a long way away from the end of the line.

In your case, a neat way of achieving the desired result is to take advantage of the simple geometry:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (i);
    \vertex [right=2cm of i] (center);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\vert{2 * sin(2 * pi / 6 r)};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\horz{2 * cos(2 * pi / 6 r)}
    \vertex [above right=\vert cm and \horz cm of center] (o1);
    \vertex [below right=\vert cm and \horz cm of center] (o2);
    \vertex (v1) at ($(center)!0.7!(i)$);
    \vertex (v2) at ($(center)!0.7!(o1)$);
    \vertex (v3) at ($(center)!0.7!(o2)$);

    \diagram* [edges=double] {
      (i) -- (v1) -- (v2) -- (v3) -- (v1),
      (v2) -- (o1),
      (v3) -- (o2),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

This initially places all of the outer vertices `2cm` from the `center` vertex.  It then places each `v1`, `v2` and `v3` vertices at `0.7` of the distance between the center and the desired outer vertex.

I realize this solution is very specific to the layout above and is not general at all.  More generally though, you can tweak the distances in the `above right=(distance) and (distance) of (vertex)`.  There are plenty of other examples that make use of this on this website, and there are examples of this within the documentation for Ti*k*Z-Feynman itself.

As for the second part of your question regarding the perpendicular lines crossing the various propagators, this is best achieved using a custom style which itself defines a new custom decoration:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\tikzfeynmanset{
  crossed/.style={
    /tikz/postaction={
      /tikz/decoration={
        show path construction,
        lineto code={
          \coordinate (tmp1) at ($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!5pt!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$);
          \draw
          ($(tmp1)!4pt!90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)
          -- ($(tmp1)!4pt!-90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$);
        },
      },
      /tikz/decorate=true,
    },
  },
  crossed'/.style={
    /tikz/postaction={
      /tikz/decoration={
        show path construction,
        lineto code={
          \coordinate (tmp1) at ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)!5pt!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$);
          \draw
          ($(tmp1)!4pt!90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)
          -- ($(tmp1)!4pt!-90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$);
        },
      },
      /tikz/decorate=true,
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (i);
    \vertex [right=2cm of i] (center);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\vert{2 * sin(2 * pi / 6 r)};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\horz{2 * cos(2 * pi / 6 r)}
    \vertex [above right=\vert cm and \horz cm of center] (o1);
    \vertex [below right=\vert cm and \horz cm of center] (o2);
    \vertex (v1) at ($(center)!0.7!(i)$);
    \vertex (v2) at ($(center)!0.7!(o1)$);
    \vertex (v3) at ($(center)!0.7!(o2)$);

    \diagram* [edges=double] {
      (i) -- (v1) -- [crossed] (v2) -- [crossed] (v3) -- [crossed'] (v1),
      (v2) -- [crossed] (o1),
      (v3) -- [crossed] (o2),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The `postaction` ensures that what follows (in this case the decoration) is drawn on top.  We then tell it to draw a decoration in the `postaction`, and the decoration type is `show path construction`.

This decoration is a specialized kind of decoration which gives access to `\tikzinputsegmentfirst` and `\tikzinputsegmentlast`, and allows for arbitrary code to be executed.  In this case, we create a temporary coordinate `5pt` away from the start and call it `tmp1`, and we then draw a straight line that is `8pt` long at a 90 degree angle to the original path going through `tmp1`.  For convenience, I have also defined a complementary style `crossed'` which places the `tmp1` coordinate `5pt` away from the end.